# Convert Multiple Files To UTF-8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, import

I have a number of files that get dumped every morning on a server. There are 9 CSV comma delimited files, varying in size from 59kb to as large as 127mb. I need to import these into a MySQL database, however the files are currently in western iso-8859-16 format and I need to convert these to UTF-8 for my import. The manual process of converting these is quite teadious as you can imagine.

Is there a script / batch file I can create to run every morning via task scheduler? Or what is the best way to try automating this process on a Windows Server 2012?

Current Script, that reads the files, but doesn't seem to convert them:

```
!/bin/bash

 Recursive file convertion CP1252 --> utf-8 
 Place this file in the root of your site, add execute permission and run
 Converts *.php, *.html, *.css, *.js files.
 To add file type by extension, e.g. *.cgi, add '-o -name "*.cgi"' to the find  command 

find ./ -name "*.csv" -o -name "*.html" -o -name "*.css" -o -name "*.js"  -type f | 
while read file
 do
  echo " $file"
  mv $file $file.icv
  iconv -f WINDOWS-1252 -t UTF-8 $file.icv > $file
  rm -f $file.icv
 done
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: This should theoretically be as simple as telling MySQL that the files are 8859-15 encoded upon import...!? (MySQL does support this encoding, doesn't it?) What's your "manual process" right now...?

Comment: Currently I am manually converting each file using EditPad Pro.

I am working on a script that I have found online as well, which will use cygwin. but I keep getting and error and no file conversion.

Script: 
#!/bin/bash
FROM=iso-8859-15
TO=UTF-8
ICONV="iconv -f $FROM -t $TO"
# Convert
find ToUTF/ -type f -name "*" | while read fn; do
cp ${fn} ${fn}.bak
$ICONV < ${fn}.bak > ${fn}
rm ${fn}.bak
done

Output:
$ sh ToUtf8.txt
ToUtf8.txt: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
ToUtf8.txt: line 10: `done'

I want to try automate the entire process, even the import

Comment: Well, how are you doing the import...? Again, if you use MySQL's CSV import feature, you should also be able to tell it what encoding the file is in and MySQL will handle it correctly.

Comment: The import is done using a script:

load data infile 'sourcefilename.csv'
into table table_name
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
ignore 1 lines;

Comment: Hmm, bummer, looks like the main problem is that MySQL *doesn't* support "Latin10" a.k.a. ISO-8859-16.

Comment: It is possible to create such a charset.

Comment: So I have made some progress on this and got a script that runs and does't throw out any errors, however, its not converting the file. It's reading them, but not converting, and ideas what's wrong?

#!/bin/bash


find ./ -name "*.csv" -o -name "*.html" -o -name "*.css" -o -name "*.js"  -type f | 
while read file
 do
  echo " $file"
  mv $file $file.icv
  iconv -f WINDOWS-1252 -t UTF-8 $file.icv > $file
  rm -f $file.icv
 done